# jquery ui datepicker with a button rather than input box

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am looking for a way to use the datepicker with a button rather than a input box. When I click the button the date picker will appear as a dropdown to the button and on click some events will fire. Somethign like the following image

[image: This is how the thing should look]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an input field and an icon (like this example):

```
<input name="Date" id="Date"  type="text" readonly  />
<a href="#" id="Date_icono" ></a>
```

You can attach the datepicker to your icon (in my case inside the A tag via CSS) like this:

```
$("#Date").datepicker();
  $("#Date_icono").click(function() { 
   $("#Date").datepicker( "show" );
  });
```

**OR**

Turns out that a simple hidden input field does the job:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />
```

And then use the buttonImage attribute for your image, like normal:

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
    buttonImage: '../images/icon_star.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'both',
 });
```

Initially I tried a text input field and then set a display:none style on it, but that caused the calendar to emerge from the top of the browser, rather than from where the user clicked. But the hidden field works as desired.